# Hibernate An assertion failure occured (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I just changed from hibernate 4.X) to hibernate 5.0, I changed my configuration file accordingly but I'm getting an weird error.

> An assertion failure occured (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session): org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: Table x_database.User not found

I hope that you can help.

Below you can see my session file and my XML config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">
            org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
        </property>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>

        <!-- Connects to the localhost database. This is for development purposes only. !-->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/x_database</property>
        <!-- Should the system flush the database before running or only update the database? !-->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">
            create
        </property>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">
            root
        </property>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">
            root
        </property>

        <mapping class="org.hva.folivora.model.user.UserEntity"></mapping>
        <mapping class="org.hva.folivora.model.user.ParentEntity"></mapping>
        <mapping class="org.hva.folivora.model.user.StudentEntity"></mapping>
        <mapping class="org.hva.folivora.model.questionanswer.QuestionEntity"></mapping>
        <mapping class="org.hva.folivora.model.global.GroupEntity"></mapping>
        <mapping class="org.hva.folivora.model.global.ThemeEntity"></mapping>

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Below my session factory.

```
    public class Database {
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            StandardServiceRegistry standardRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").build();
            Metadata metadata = new MetadataSources(standardRegistry).getMetadataBuilder().build();
            return metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static Session getSession() {

        return getSessionFactory().openSession();
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        final org.hibernate.Session session = getSession();
        try {
            System.out.println("querying all the managed entities...");
            final Map metadataMap = session.getSessionFactory().getAllClassMetadata();
            for (Object key : metadataMap.keySet()) {
                final ClassMetadata classMetadata = (ClassMetadata) metadataMap.get(key);
                final String entityName = classMetadata.getEntityName();
                final Query query = session.createQuery("from " + entityName);
                System.out.println("executing: " + query.getQueryString());
                for (Object o : query.list()) {
                    System.out.println("  " + o);
                }
            }
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }

    }
}
```

Full stacktrace below.

```
                01-May-2016 18:18:08.136 SEVERE [http-nio-8079-exec-4] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [IJBurg API/BACKEND] in context with path [] threw exception [org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError] with root cause
 org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: Table pad_ijburg.User not found
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getTableId(AbstractEntityPersister.java:5139)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.JoinedSubclassEntityPersister.<init>(JoinedSubclassEntityPersister.java:433)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:344)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:465)
    at org.hva.folivora.Database.buildSessionFactory(Database.java:26)
    at org.hva.folivora.Database.<clinit>(Database.java:19)
    at org.hva.folivora.MyResource.getIt(MyResource.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:205)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:471)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:425)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:383)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:336)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:223)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1096)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:760)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1480)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My sessionfactory

```
   package org.hva.folivora;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.Metadata;
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.metadata.ClassMetadata;

import java.util.Map;

public class Database {
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            StandardServiceRegistry standardRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").build();
            Metadata metadata = new MetadataSources(standardRegistry).getMetadataBuilder().build();
            return metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static Session getSession() {

        return getSessionFactory().openSession();
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        final org.hibernate.Session session = getSession();
        try {
            System.out.println("querying all the managed entities...");
            final Map metadataMap = session.getSessionFactory().getAllClassMetadata();
            for (Object key : metadataMap.keySet()) {
                final ClassMetadata classMetadata = (ClassMetadata) metadataMap.get(key);
                final String entityName = classMetadata.getEntityName();
                final Query query = session.createQuery("from " + entityName);
                System.out.println("executing: " + query.getQueryString());
                for (Object o : query.list()) {
                    System.out.println("  " + o);
                }
            }
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }

    }
}

package org.hva.folivora.model.user;

import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "User", schema = "pad_ijburg")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class UserEntity {
    private int idUser;
    private String email;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String password;
    private Boolean admin = false;
    private Boolean teacher = false;

    public UserEntity(){

    }

    public UserEntity(String email, String firstName, String lastName, String password, Boolean admin, Boolean teacher){
        this.email = email;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.password = password;
        this.admin = admin;
        this.teacher = teacher;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "teacher")
    public Boolean getTeacher() {
        return teacher;
    }

    public void setTeacher(Boolean teacher) {
        this.teacher = teacher;
    }

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "idUser", nullable = false, updatable = false, unique = true)
    public int getIdUser() {
        return idUser;
    }

    public void setIdUser(int idUser) {
        this.idUser = idUser;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "email", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "firstName")
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "lastName")
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "password")
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "admin")
    public Boolean getAdmin() {
        return admin;
    }

    public void setAdmin(Boolean admin) {
        this.admin = admin;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        UserEntity that = (UserEntity) o;

        if (idUser != that.idUser) return false;
        if (email != null ? !email.equals(that.email) : that.email != null) return false;
        if (firstName != null ? !firstName.equals(that.firstName) : that.firstName != null) return false;
        if (lastName != null ? !lastName.equals(that.lastName) : that.lastName != null) return false;
        if (password != null ? !password.equals(that.password) : that.password != null) return false;
        if (admin != null ? !admin.equals(that.admin) : that.admin != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = idUser;
        result = 31 * result + (email != null ? email.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (firstName != null ? firstName.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (lastName != null ? lastName.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (password != null ? password.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (admin != null ? admin.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Anyone? I need a fix!

Comment: I check this code with Hibernate 5.1 and my mapping – everything works. Please, add a full stack trace of the exception and your entities.

Comment: @v.ladynev I've added the stacktrace to the orginal post.

Comment: @TVH7 can you paste your `org.hva.folivora.model.user.UserEntity`

Comment: Please, add a `Database.buildSessionFactory` method.

Comment: @v.ladynev I've added the sessionfactory.

Comment: @GautamSavaliya Done ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgrade to Hibernate 4.1-FINAL and it should work again. Apparently Hibernate 5 has a lot of trouble still.. (Or they totally removed the joined strategy) Quite sad..

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it has something to do with the @inheritance. When I remove the inheritance joined type it will work. I still cannot get further since joined inheritance is something I still need.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `USER` is a reserved keyword in MySQL. It can be a reason of the problem. Please, use plural names

```
@Table(name = "users", schema = "pad_ijburg")
public class User {

}
```

You need to have `pad_ijburg` schema in the database. And you need to update or create the schema with `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update`, if you don't do so.

Next time, enable SQL log and provide log with Hibernate bootstrap. Hibernate provides information about SQL for tables creation.

Comment: I have always learned from db admins not to use plural. User is indeed a protected word, but it worked before so why change it. I've changed it to test, but it did not work. Update won't create tables, I use create but it still won't create the table since I think there something wrong with the session factory. 

Please check the sessionfactory, you might see some errors there which I don't see.

Comment: @TVH7 Your admins are strange persons. I have already made a comment that your session factory configuration works fine with my test entities.

Comment: Well sadly I still get the assertion error... 05-May-2016 17:36:47.432 ERROR [http-nio-8079-exec-4] org.hibernate.AssertionFailure.<init> HHH000099: an assertion failure occured (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session): org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: Table pad_ijburg.Users not found

Comment: @TVH7 Please, enable SQL in the `hibernate.properties` and add a log with Hibernate startup (with `create` table, information about mapped entities, etc)

Comment: There is no SQL being generated since it is an assertion failure. I have SQL on but it is not generating. Again it has something to do with inheritance..